# How to build a bootstrapper for multiple MSI files?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, burn, wix3.7

I've got following problem: With WiX 3.7 I have built an installer which creates several localized MSI files, for example:

```
..\bin\x86\Release\en-us\myProject.msi
..\bin\x86\Release\fr-fr\myProject.msi
..\bin\x86\Release\de-de\myProject.msi
```

Furthermore, I created a [Burn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) bootstrapper project which should ensure that .NET 4.5 is installed:

```
...
<Chain>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Web"/>      
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.myProject.TargetPath)"></MsiPackage>
</Chain>
...
```

Now I have expected that the Burn bootstrapper project creates:

```
..\bin\x86\Release\en-us\myProject.exe
..\bin\x86\Release\fr-fr\myProject.exe
..\bin\x86\Release\de-de\myProject.exe
```

but MsiPackage expects a single file.

Is it generally possible to make the Burn project work as I expect?

If this is not the case, is it possible to get to know how the exact name of the created MSI file? I can not hard code the MSI file name, because the output name can vary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible... If you are using [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) or something similar you can build it as you're building your MSI packages.

Or you can use a simple script which will call candle.exe with parameter `-dYOUR_VARIABLE=myProject.msi`.

See *[Working with MSBuild](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/msbuild.htm)* for more information.